# Deploy python with keras in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, keras, aws-lambda

Currently, I am trying to deploy a deep learning model into aws Lambda.
The model requires keras package. 
I followed the steps in AWS web site for deploying python script. And the only difference is Lambda has size limitation - 50MB, so I used **find $env_path -name "*.so" |xargs strip** to reduce the size.
However, after I deployed this into AWS Lambda and kicked of test run, it gave me the below error.
[error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qY6RZ.jpg)
Is there anyone having this deployment experience?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am having the same exact issue. I believe error 38 is related to multiprocessing, and because lambda instances do not have shared memory (/dev/shm), multiprocessing isn't possible. I have done some debugging, even trying to set tensorflow into single core mode before importing Keras, but it seems like the issue always strikes while I import keras. I too did the same stripping to reduce the size. I wonder if it would work if this command did not include tensorflow, but that is getting down to C, which is beyond me.

Comment: I changed my solution. I use an EC2 instance rather than a Lambda function. There are two reasons I changed my solution. Firstly, Lambda has the size limitation. I checked on AWS forum, it has been fixed. Secondly, because I want to use the model to predict something, the model file only needs to be loaded once at the beginning rather than event triggered based. I wrap this model in an API, which can be invoked by external web site.

Comment: I resolved the issue by using the keras API that is built into tensorflow 1.4. You're right that there is a lot of overhead time involved in loading TF into memory, but it is possible to keep a lamba function "warm" using AWS cloudwatch setting it to ping your function  every few minutes. That way at least the API can be called in a massively concurrently if needed. When lambda is warm I'm getting a 1s response time on a 70mb model.